# Can not read property in script

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, gallery

I use lightGallery script and i need to put list of items to lightGallery settings script but console get me error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

This is part of my script

```
$.ajax({
                    url: post_link,
                    success: function(data) {
                        function echoimage () {
                            jsonObj = [];
                            $("img",data).each(function() {
                                imgsrc =  $(this).attr("src");
                                altext =  $(this).attr("alt");

                                item = {}
                                item ["src"] = imgsrc;
                                item ["caption"] = altext;
                                item ["thumb"] = imgsrc;
                                item ["desc"] = altext;
                                jsonObj.push(item);
                            });
                        }

                        echoimage();
                        console.log(jsonObj);

                        $(this).lightGallery({
                            dynamic: true,
                            caption: true,
                            thumbnail: false,
                            desc: false,
                            speed: 500,
                            dynamicEl: JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
                        });

                    }
                })
```

Comment: You don't have `match` word in script you have provided. It seems that it is internal error in some function you are calling. Try to look in console inside what function this error happened?

Comment: This function is in lightGallery.min.js Firefox get me error: TypeError: e is undefined